# Office Excel add-in (web app) load/save document

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

With the new Office Excel add-in model, there is a way to do the following on any platform (online, desktop and iOS):

1. load a document from the server?
2. save the document back to the server (we can use DOcument.getFileAsync, but this method is not supported on iOS host https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync)?

We have managed to successfully implement all the above for Word documents.